# Using Dribbble API with PHP

Tags: php, dribbble-api

I want to get my Dribbble shots intro my portfolio website using the Dribbble API. I'm not a PHP guy, that's why I don't know how to use the API (http://dribbble.com/api).

How can I get shots into my HTML or PHP page?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't write the code for you, you might want to look at their developer docs and consider hiring someone to get it done if you can't yourself.

Comment: First Google search result... http://buildinternet.com/2010/11/using-the-dribbble-api-with-php/

Comment: I've already try that one and it dosen't work for me :(

Comment: Then you should post your code, and the errors that you get.

Comment: I can't post the answare here because I don't have much reputation so far. Here is what I tried to say: http://prntscr.com/98hc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this JS and change the user info to your name

```
// variables used

var slgoetzShots;
var slgoetzNum = 1;
var active = "Slgoetz";



// slgoetz shots
function slgoetzGet(pageNum){
var url = "http://api.dribbble.com/slgoetz/shots";
$.get(
    url, {page:pageNum, per_page:"30"},
    function(data){
        slgoetzShots = data;
        slgoetzNum += 1;
        render(slgoetzShots);
    },
    "jsonp"
);
};



// slgoetzGet: render
function getSimon(){
if (active != "slgoetz"){
    slgoetzGet("1");
    $('#'+active).removeClass("active");
    $('#Everyone').addClass("active");
    active = "Simon Goetz";
    slgoetzNum = 1;
};
};

//popular shots is default
getSimon("1")


var inner = ""; 
var innerP1 = '<li><div class="dribbble"><div class="shot"><a href="';
var innerP2 = '"><img src="';
var innerP3 = '"></a></div><div class="likes">'  
var innerP4 = ' Likes</div><div class="comments">'
var innerP5 = ' Comments</div><div class="name">'
var innerp6 = '</div></div></li>'


function render(filter){
for (var i = 0; i<filter.shots.length;i++){
    inner = inner + innerP1 + filter.shots[i].url + innerP2 +         filter.shots[i].image_url + innerP3 + filter.shots[i].likes_count + innerP4 +        filter.shots[i].comments_count + innerP5 + filter.shots[i].title + innerp6;

};

$('.gallery').html(inner);
inner = "";
};


function loadMore(){
switch(active){


    case "Simon Goetz":
        inner = $('.gallery').html();
        slgoetzGet(slgoetzNum.toString());
        break;
};
 };
```

HTML add a .gallery class to a div

Comment: Great job, but I belive that URL variable must receive a HTTPS protocol (SSL). In your case would be: var url = "h t t p s://api.dribbble.com/slgoetz/shots"  
ps: without the spaces of course :)

Answer (score 1):

you may consider to use some jquery plugin to help you to import shots to your site, here is an example (http://gbin1.com/gb/demoviewer/360/06242ba0-40a1-45fd-946f-cc89e0df64c9/index.html.htm), which make use of jQUery plugin called Jribbble v1.0.0 , hope helps!