# Cannot load JS class

Tags: javascript, html, dribbble-api

I am trying to display my dribbble feed on my portfolio site using someone's tip found here: [Using Dribbble API with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587154/using-dribbble-api-with-php)

I changed the .js per his suggestion but have no idea how to add the code to the HTML. I ended up doing this but it cannot be right:

`<div id="content" class="home col eight">
                <div id="dribbblefeed" class=".gallery">
                </div>
            </div>`

The site is currently run through a CMS called Stacey App. You can view the test site here: http://marcna.sh/testsite/testsite/ a simple view source should show you all you need.

Thanks so much for your help. I was hopeing to have this finalized by 2 today but it didn't happen:-/

Comment: You sure that shouldn't be `class="gallery"`, w/o the leading dot?

Comment: fair point but that wasnt loading either -- see the testsite/testsite --currently has the gallery without hte dot

Comment: What about spelling "dribbblefeed" with 3 b's?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I believe you are naming your classes incorrectly. `class="home col eight"` means this element has three class names - "home", "col" and "eight". And ".gallery" is an invalid class name, it must start with a letter, and may contain only letters, digits, hyphens and underscores.

Comment: @Juhana haha that was dumb. i updated the css but still nothing loads

Comment: @Zemljoradnik the .gallery has been updated on the staging site. the `class="home col eight"` is default to stacey app

Comment: @Zemljoradnik multiple classes on an element are not only legit, but quite useful.

Comment: @ ultranaut I agree, but as I sad I wasn't sure what he is trying to do, it looked like a mistake to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing line 27 in your dribbbgallery.js, from

```
if (active != "marcnash"){
```

to

```
if (active === "marcnash"){
```

The way it is right now, your script is NOT loading images when variable `active` equals `marcnash`, and it is set to `marcnash` in the line 5.

Comment: Amazing! this loaded the images. Now it looks like I have some styling to correct. Do you know if this needs to be done from the .js file or it should be done from the stylesheet?

Comment: Whenever it is possible, it should be done using CSS, not JS. Since these images have no html class, you should probably use something like `.shot img` (select all elements with "img" tag inside elements with class "shot") to select all the images in the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues going on in your code. First, you need to remove the leading dot in you class attribute:

```
<div id="dribbblefeed" class="gallery">
```

And second, the javascript you're using depends on jQuery, but you haven't included it on your page. Add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

to your page, ideally at the bottom.

**Edit**: Like I said, there's (at least) three issues...

In the code you got from @goetz at [Using Dribbble API with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587154/using-dribbble-api-with-php), he (she?) has this:

```
var slgoetzShots;
var slgoetzNum = 1;
var active = "Slgoetz";

// ...

function getSimon(){
  if (active != "slgoetz"){

    // magic happens here

  };
};

getSimon("1");
```

Notice the conditional statement for `active != "slgoetz"` uses a lowercase `s`, so the condition evaluates to `true` and the code runs. In your modified version, you've (quite reasonably in my opinion) "fixed" that, you're initializing `active` as `marcnash` (lowercase `m`) and then testing against that value in the function:

```
var marcnashShots;
var marcnashNum = 1;
var active = "marcnash";

// ...

function getSimon(){
  if (active != "marcnash"){

     // magic happens here

  };
};
```

Since that's evaluating as `false`, the code to build the gallery doesn't run. I'd guess that @slgoetz adapted some code from another source that allowed for more configuration and reloading of the gallery, and managed to get it working by accident more or less.

Basically if you just change the `active` initialization to `var active = null`, you should be all set (unless there's still another issue I've missed). Once you have it running, I'd strongly suggest refactoring the code to better suit your purposes, if you just need to load your gallery and leave it at that, then there's code in there that's completely unnecessary.

Comment: See my update, you should add it to your page at the bottom where your other script tags are, I'd probably make it the first one.

Comment: i updated it but still not showing up. could it be interacting with the javscript for stacey app?

Comment: any other ideas? I made some changes such as `<div id="dribbblefeed" class="dgallery">` and renamed the js to "dribbbgallery.js" incase it was conflicting with some native function...

Comment: thanks! I ended up following the advice of @zemljoradnik who found another fix. right now I'm working towards adding styles so the gallery looks good. I really appreciate all your time and effort!